# looking for a well laid out proof/construction of the reals and complex numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

I have seen a proof of the rationals in a second year Abstract algebra course. i know i have seen a proof that the irrationals exist. ( i think anyway) can someone give me a link to a proof or textbook that actually does the whole construction of the reals. When i took Algerbra the prof said it was too much work to write out the construction of the reals as it was rather large. Also its been awhile since i have been doing math so a construction that doesn't omit things because they are obvious would be great. 
Also i think i have actually seen a proof of the complex numbers but if someone has a straightforward construction of them laying around i'd appreciate that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rudin does the Dedekind construction at the end of his first chapter in *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.  Constructing $\mathbb{C}$ from $\mathbb{R}$ is much easier; simply take $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ and define addition and multiplication (I'm not certain where Rudin does this, but I'd be surprised if he didn't do it somewhere in the same chapter).

Be aware that the construction of $\mathbb{R}$ (using the Dedekind construction, at least, which doesn't really require any prerequisite knowledge) is very tedious, long, and in some ways unenlightening, so your Algebra professor didn't include it for good reason.

Comment: Yeah i rmeber the Complex numbers being a rather simple construction and i am quite familiar with Dedekind Cuts and lub's and the continuity that depends so much on that property from higher up Calculus.

Comment: @Faust7 Yes, the LUB property is, quite literally, what defines $\mathbb{R}$.  Being familiar with Dedekind cuts is useful, but the meat of the construction is simply checking the field axioms (LUB property follows rather quickly, but the field axioms do not).